# What's the difference between operator product expansion and perturbation?

Tags: operators, definition, perturbation-theory, non-perturbative

Operator product expansion and perturbation theory both looked somewhat similar to Taylor/Laurent series expansion.

Quote: Conformal Field Theory, Philippe Di Francesco, Pierre Mathieu, David Senechal, Page 127 Eq. 5.72

> "$$\displaystyle A(z)B(w)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^N \frac{\{AB\}_n (w)}{(z-w)^n}$$ where the composite fields $\{AB\}_n(w)$ are nonsingular at $w=z$. "

and in perturbation theory

> $\displaystyle A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n \epsilon^n$  where $A_n$ were some operators.

If excluded the singular power in operator product expansion, and take $w\rightarrow 0$ to be a fixed number, they appeared to be exactly the same.

However, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_product_expansion), operator product expansion was non-perturbative.How could they take almost identical form but one was "perturbative" and one was "non perturbative"?

What's the difference between operator product expansion and perturbation?

Comment: What is the perturbative parameter in the OPE? It can't be the spacetime coordinates — these aren't parameters of the field theory, they're coordinates for the space the fields live on.

Comment: You can't exclude the non singular term in the OPE. It's the most important part.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why OPE and perturbation theory look similar is that they both use a Taylor or Laurent series expansion, but in different variables. OPE uses a series expansion in powers of the distance between two fields, while perturbation theory uses a series expansion in powers of the coupling constant. The two expansions are not equivalent, and they have different domains of validity and applicability.
The answer to your question depends on how you define perturbative and non-perturbative quantum field theory.

One possible definition is that perturbative QFT is based on a series expansion in a small coupling constant, while non-perturbative QFT does not rely on such an expansion. In this case, OPE and perturbation theory are not equivalent, but rather complementary approaches to QFT. OPE can be used to describe the short-distance behavior of quantum fields, while perturbation theory can be used to calculate scattering amplitudes and other observables. However, OPE can also be applied to non-perturbative QFTs, such as lattice QFT or axiomatic QFT, where the interaction is not constructed by multiplying free field operators. In this case, OPE and perturbation theory are not directly comparable, but rather different ways of defining and studying QFT. OPE can be seen as a generalization of perturbation theory that does not require a small parameter to expand the solution.